# SQL List the representative that handles the most customers

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have 2 tables `SALESREP` and `CUSTOMER`
I need to find out which salesrep has most customers

I have the following code:

```
select rep_lname, count(cust_num) 
from customer inner join salesrep 
on customer.REP_NUM = SALESREP.REP_NUM 
group by rep_lname
```

This gives me all the rows with the number of customers each salesrep has, instead I need only one row that has the most customers.

How can I find the row with MAX num of customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES rep_lname, COUNT(cust_num)
FROM customer inner join salesrep 
  ON customer.REP_NUM = SALESREP.REP_NUM 
GROUP BY rep_lname
ORDER BY count(cust_num) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select rep_lname, count(cust_num) 
from customer inner join salesrep 
on customer.REP_NUM = SALESREP.REP_NUM 
group by rep_lname order by count(cust_num) desc limit 1;
```

I'm sure there's another way using `having`, but I can't seem to figure it out at the moment. Perhaps somebody else will chime in with it?

Comment: There is a chance that more than one row has the max number so it should not limit to one row.

Comment: no that one doesn't work, plus if it would i cannot go with it...we haven't learned that in class yet. There should be easier way

Comment: @jani OP wanted "only one row that has the most customers."